# Reference frames in Minkowskian spacetime

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames

I want to make sure that I understand the concept of reference frame in Minkowskian spacetime.

---

Suppose that $(\mathbb{R}^4, \eta)$ is $4$-dimensional Minkowskian spacetime. Then what we call "reference frame" would be a choice of orthonormal basis vectors $\{e_{0}|_{p}, e_1|_{p}, e_2|_{p}, e_3|_{p}\}\subset T_{p}\mathbb{R}^4$ where $\{e_1|_{p}, e_2|_{p}, e_3|_{p}\}$ are spacelike, and $\{e_0|_{p}\}$ is timelike. In the absence of curvature, the parallel-transport $f : T_{p}\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow T_{ p'}\mathbb{R}^4$ is simply identity $f = I$, and so, $\{e_0|_{p}, e_1|_{p}, e_2|_{p}, e_3|_{p}\}$ is also a vector space basis for $T_{p^{‘}}\mathbb{R}^4$. In fact, there’s an identification $(T_{p}\mathbb{R}^4, \eta) = (\mathbb{R}^4, \eta)$. Therefore, every $4$-vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^4$ admits a unique representation

$$v = t e_0|_{p} +xe_1|_{p} + ye_2|_{p} + z e_3|_{p}\rightarrow [v] = \pmatrix{t\\ x \\ y \\ z}\tag{1}$$

Since we can move the reference frame freely, we can consider a coinciding reference frame $\{e^{*}_0|_{p}, e^{*}_1|_{p}, e^{*}_2|_{p}, e^{*}_3|_{p}\}\subset T_{p}\mathbb{R}^4$ that starts moving with velocity $v$ along $x$-direction. Now, $(1)$ reads for this reference frame as

$$v = t^{*} e^{*}_0|_{p}+x^{*}e^{*}_1|_{p} + y^{*}e^{*}_2|_{p} + z^{*}e^{*}_3|_{p}\rightarrow [v] = \pmatrix{t^{*} \\ x^{*} \\ y^{*} \\ z^{*}}$$

Where coordinates are given, for Cartesian frame fields, by Lorentz transformations:

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}t^{*}&=\gamma \left(t-{\frac{vx}{c^{2}}}\right)\space\space x^{*}=\gamma \left(x-vt\right)\space\space y^{*}=y\space\space z^{*}=z\end{aligned}}}\tag{2}$$

---

Is there any flaw in my understanding?

Comment: It looks fine to me. Just remember that base vectors change as well, to keep invariance of the vector

Comment: This is accurate.

Comment: Try not to get any more reputation points. Relativity 101 looks kinda cool.